# ASP.Net role based form authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, authorization

If I want to create a customized ASP.Net MVC3 form based authentication, what are the interfaces I should implement? I want to do the role based form authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement a custom [Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.aspx) provider and a [RoleProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.aspx). Those are 2 abstract classes that have lots of methods but you don't need necessarily to implement all of them. Only those that you intend to use. Here's [an article](http://www.danharman.net/2011/06/23/asp-net-mvc-3-custom-membership-provider-with-repository-injection/) which illustrates some of the basic steps.